# Azure Devops Query to find Daily hours spent on Work item

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

I have to find out time spend by a resource on a Task.

let say,

- There are 3 Task (Task-A,Task-B,Task-C)
- There are 3 User    (User-A,User-B,User-C)
- All the Task have Original estimate of 8 hours
- on Day 1 All the User have work 2 hours on their respective tasks

**So I should get a result of 2**

I am using **Azure Work Item query** to calculate and display the results.

[image]

I am not understanding what should be done to calculate the daily work done on a task.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Sorry but your example is very vague...
**So I should get a result of 2** ... What is your expected outcome? A list of all items with the effort that already has been spent on?

Comment: 2 is the actual hours spend on the task.  .  I want to calculate it on daily basis

Answer (score 4):

For this issue , you can add  **Completed Work** and **Remaining work** column to the query.This can show the hours the tasks has spent and remaining work hours in the query. 
Based on these two fields, you can calculate the daily hours spent on work item.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have those options enabled. My question is can we get how many hours are spent the respective task per day.

Comment: As far as I know, there is currently no easy way to get how many hours are spent the respective task per day. You can track the completed work of each day in the history of the work item then calculate the time spent on the day, but this is tedious. You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site.Our PM and Product Group are reviewing these suggestion regularly and considering take it as plan

Comment: @Eddie did you requested the feature? Hug-lin is there any plan or update on this? thanks to both

Answer (score 3):

> Azure Devops Query to find Daily hours spent on Work item

AFAIK, Azure devops does not focus on micromanaging and focus on low value metrics.

So, Azure devops doesn't track the time spent on a per day basis. It keeps track of the total time spent. If you want a per person per day value, you'll have to go through the iterations/workitem history and calculate the running difference.

If you really looking for a TimeReporting for the work items of per person, I suggest that you take a look at a third party yool like Timetracker:

[Timetracker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=7pace.Timetracker)

> New to version 5.0.! **Individual**, team, and custom reports powered by
>   version 3 of the REST-based reporting API. 7+ customizable widget
>   types that let you see data that you need, how you need it. In
>   addition to the six default reports in Reporting, users can create
>   custom reports for individuals or teams.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is keeping track of hours per task, period, that is low-value micromanagement.  If your employer insists on it, then the only way to help increase the value is to make the hours accurate. Without a daily view, employees have no easy way to verify their time entry is accurate.  The linked Timetracker integration looks great for this, however, our org is ditching a nicer time tracking system already in favor of using "one system" to post time in ADO to save costs, so that's likely to be a no-go :(

Answer (score 1):

You can [Analinics Views and Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/create-quick-report?view=azure-devops). For example, you can add your custom view:

[image]

Then use it in Power BI:

[image]